# Flex 4 image object returning as MovieClip object

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I am working on a custom context menu in Flex4. The context menu itself works fine but I am looking for a way to tell if the ContextMenuEvent mouseTarget is an image. As it stands, the mouseTarget shows that it is a "[object MovieClip]". Which is strange because I have no movie clips in my application, only image containers. Any idea what is going on?

```
private function openContextMenu(e:ContextMenuEvent):void {
    Alert.show(e.mouseTarget.toString());// shows [object MovieClip] when it should show [Object Image]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are your image containers MovieClips or are they Loader objects?

Comment: The image containers are <mx:Image> items. I later add the "source" property to based on data loaded from a fileRef's .load operation.

Comment: You'll probably need to dig deeper into the MovieClip to see if it's child is an Image, etc. The Image class extends many many Objects, least of all might be the bitmap that is what is shown. You may want to explore the BitmapImage class in Flex, may provide a more direct route to what you want.

Comment: I have figured it out. Cant post an answer yet though because of my rep level. Will post the answer in a few hours or tomorrow morning. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set mouseChildren on the Image to false, then the MouseEvent will refer to the Image:

```
if (event.target is Image) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This was perfect. Misunderstanding my quick read of mouseChildren in the docs I tried true and gave up on that when it didnt work. So, mouseChildren = false on the image tag was the solution. Probably saved milisecond from my solution as well as a little bit of memory and a few lines of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after a few more hours of research I came up with the below attached to the contextMenu's item select event listener. I am sure there has to be a better way to do this, but until then...

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(this.mouseX, this.mouseY)).length; i++)
{
    if(getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(this.mouseX, this.mouseY))[i].parent.parent is Image)
    {
        //do what I need to do
    }
}
```

Thanks NHubben for your input. It got me going down the right path of looking at children.

Comment: This is not a generic solution, and it will break if you happen to change the container or child.

Answer (score 0):

The component name `Image` has no relevance concerning what makes it up.  The flex inheritance is:  Image -- SWFLoader -- UIComponent -- FlexSprite -- [...] (from [mx.controls.Image docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Image.html)).

So what you need to do is understand what you actually have when you bring it into a AS3 environment.  It seems like it gets wrapped up in a MovieClip to allow it be in the Flash's display list.  It also looks like you have to go through a loader, but I'm not sure of that.

Run a test or two to find out what the object is actually made up of:

```
// not foolproof, and will break on some stuff, 
// so you will have to fix this as needed:
private function loopDisplay(obj:Sprite):void
{
    trace(obj.name + ": " + obj);
    if (obj.numChildren > 0)
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < this.numChildren; i++)
        {
            loopDisplay(obj.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

If you put this in a mouse down handler, then you can see what is actually there.

However, the `event.target` or `event.currentTarget` should also hold the menu item object, so you can also just loop into those objects and see what is in them.